# Unable to Post Questions

Tags: support, questions, post-ban

I was just now trying to post a question via my Android based smartphone using the App on Physics SE but it is not accepting my question and sending a message stating that we are no longer accepting questions from this user. However I have neither been banned nor held guilty for any sort of misconduct so why is it so?